# Retaining user details on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

On login request, I am sending id, password & In return I'm getting unique token key, uid, email & uname and saving them in local. after user logged in, If I refresh the page, header changes & ask again to login. How can I retain those values even after page refresh.
Here is my code:-

```
angular.module('feApp').controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $uibModalInstance, login, appSettings, appServices, lclStorage) {
$scope.userLogin = function() {
    var checkbox = $("#rememberme"),
        userPwd = $("#regU_Pwd")
    var requestParam = {
        "email_id": $scope.user.email_id,
        "password": $scope.user.password
    }
    if (checkbox.prop('checked')) {
        lclStorage.set('user_Det.user_name', $('#regU_Id').val())
        lclStorage.set('user_Det.user_pwd', $('#regU_Pwd').val())
    };
    appServices.doAPIRequest(appSettings.appAPI_ci.logininfo.overviewData, requestParam, null, 'userData').then(function(data) {
        $scope.bookmarkData = data.Bookmarked_careers;
        $rootScope.userDetails = data.User_details;
        $scope.error_Message = data.errors;
        $scope.loginStatus = data.message;
        if ($scope.loginStatus == 'success') {
            $scope.login = login;
            $scope.login.showLogin = false;
            $uibModalInstance.close($scope.login);
            $rootScope.login_Status = "true";
            lclStorage.set('userDetails', $scope.userDetails)
        } else {
            $(".login_Alert").removeClass('hidden');
            $rootScope.login_Status = "false";
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: What is usually done is generating a token from the server once the user logs-in, and send it to the client. Then the token can be stored in browsers local storage (or cookie). The token is sent to the server with each subsequent request so the server knows who the client is.
Usually, there is an expiration time set on the tokens.
Take this random article about token-based authentication in Angular : https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth

Comment: subsequent request you mean page reload or login or any other, & should I add this token to the request params in the subsequent request ?

Comment: By subsequent I mean after refreshing or not. You can put the token in an HTTP header so it won't make a difference to make a GET or POST request. I usually see authentication headers like this :

     'Authorization: bearer <theToken>'